# Opensource software of linux mint for timemanagement and deadlines

Tags: linux, time-management

I am using Linux Mint 19. I need to organize many deadlines and has to schedule tasks for the future.

Is there any good (slightly intelligent) open source software that can allow me to schedule my tasks and has to show me (probably as a popup) the deadlines at regular intervals of time?

Answer (score 1):

### [Taskcoach](http://www.taskcoach.org/)

- Open Source
- Organize tasks and subtasks
- Can be organized in projects and categories
- Tasks can have deadlines and priority
- Effort tracking
- Notifications

See the full [list of features](http://www.taskcoach.org/features.html) on the [homepage](http://www.taskcoach.org).

---

Install it with your package manager

```
sudo apt install taskcoach
```

---

[image: Taskcoach Screenshot]